# Question title isn’t obtained from the http link

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, markdown-preview, http

In the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323695/339911) preview both the http and https links are looked same:

> [image: preview]

At the same time the normal view contains a raw link instead of the question title for http version:

> [image: normal view]

Both links are clickable and referencing to the same post.

Comment: Maybe a better solution: automatically rewrite all SE URLs to HTTPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out with build rev `2020.1.8.35735`.

The bug here was a regression from when we switched default URLs from http to https. The server-side code that detects question URLs had to consider both cases (http and https), but was relying on a default parameter value for the http case instead of explicitly probing for it (`site.Url()` instead of `site.Url(https: false)`).

Comment: Related post in sandbox still showing only one title despite new build.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ typing in a new answer box an HTTP URL will show the question title, though. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTO23.png